# Change 2nd parameter of method 'YoutubeRecyclerAdapter' from 'Context' to 'Callback<...>'

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am facing issue, using RecyclerView, Retrofit with custom Adapter class, getting:

```
Change 2nd parameter of method 'VideoRecyclerAdapter' from 'Context' to 'Callback<ArrayList<VideoPojo>>'
```

**Adapter.java:**

```
public VideoRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<VideoPojo> personList, Context context) {
        mPersonList = personList;
        mPref = context.getSharedPreferences("person", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mEditor = mPref.edit();
    }
```

**Activity.java:**

```
videoAPI.getData(strJSON, new Callback<ArrayList<VideoPojo>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(ArrayList<VideoPojo> videoPojoList, Response response) {

            try {
                videoList = videoPojoList;
                videoAdapter = new VideoRecyclerAdapter(videoList, this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(videoAdapter);

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }

    });
```

**API.java:**

```
public interface VideoAPI {

    @GET("/list/{name}")
   void getData(@Path("name") String name, Callback<ArrayList<VideoPojo>> response);

}
```

Comment: please do not downvote my question ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change this line

```
videoAdapter = new VideoRecyclerAdapter(videoList, this);
```

to

```
videoAdapter = new VideoRecyclerAdapter(videoList, YourActivity.this);
```

under inner interface **this** is refereed as `Callback<ArrayList<VideoPojo>>`. You need `Application` or `Activity` **Context**.

Comment: ohhh... sorry I have not tried that :) thanks --- ticked as useful and will accept in few minutes

Comment: yeah.. and one more silly question, In Adapter getting cannot resolve method getContext() -- Picasso.with(getContext())

Comment: you already have context in `VideoRecyclerAdapter Constructor` as a second argument . so use it

Comment: Ok I used like this: this.mContext = context;